# UICollectionViewCells subview rendered wrong after scrolling

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The CollectionViewCell i subclassed contains just a UILabel.
To get the grid i add the UILabel with a CGRectInset to the cell.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
        self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.bounds, 1.0, 1.0)];
        self.label.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.label.layer.shouldRasterize = true;
        [self addSubview:self.label];
    }
    return self;
}
```

As requested

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"indexPathSection: %i in row: %i", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
    MyCVCell *cell = (MyCVCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[self.cData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.label.text = str;

    return cell;
}
```

All looks fine till i scroll. Any ideas what could be the cause?

Before scroll
[image: views rendered right]
scrolling down
[image: scrolling down]
scrolling up
[image: scrolling back up]

Comment: Please post your code from `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @0x7fffffff added it to question

Comment: try adding your subviews to the cells contentView instead of directly to the cell?

Comment: @wattson12 tried that, doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you ever work this out or at least come up with something that worked for you?

Comment: @darbid yeah, just added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that subviews in the cell didn't resize. Easiest solution (at least for UILabels) is to set  autoresizingmask to: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight.

Comment: ah thanks pekoe.  I was hoping you had a auto layout answer but anyway good to see you got it solved.